# Ndb default order does not preserve insertion order

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I used GAE and NDB for a project. I just noticed that if I create several objects, and then I retrieve the list of these objects the order is not preserved (i use the `fetch()` on the object).

This is a screenshot of the admin page, which shows the same problem: 
[image: screenshot]

as you *may* (if it's too small [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u3avq9xm1ab2grz/Screenshot%202015-04-15%2012.13.18.png?dl=0) is the link) see i've several `sessions`. Now, i created the sessions that have as name `day` in order, from 0 to 7.

But as you see the order is not preserved.

I checked and actually the `keys` are not incremental. Neither the `id` (`id` should be incremental, shouldn't it? but anyway in some classes, not this one, I used a hand-made key, so there will be no `id`).

Is there a way to preserve insertion order? 
(or it's just a strange behaviour? or it's my bad?)

PS: if you want to have a look at the code: [this](https://github.com/gymcentral/gymcentral/blob/master/models.py#L277) is the session model which extends [this](https://github.com/esseti/gaebasepy/blob/master/gc_models.py#L15) class i made

Comment: didn't get. where should i pass a dict?

Comment: id's are deliberately allocated in a sparse fashion to improve performance. If you need incrementing ID's you can pre-allocate id's and then manage their use yourself.  There is nothing in the docs that would imply an strict ordering of id's and I would be very surprised to see that behaviour.

Comment: coming from an "SQL world" I implied order, my bad.

Comment: Its pretty important to "forget" almost everything you have been doing from the "SQL world" when you start working with the datastore.  I personally always thought it a mistake to include GQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither `keys` nor `id`s are strictly incremental (and incremental by one) in `ndb`. You can set your own `id`s and assure they autoincrement properly.

Or you can add to your model(s) a `DateTimeProperty`:

```
created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

And in your view you can use a filter to sort the entities by the date of insertion, for ex:

```
posts = Post.query().order(-Post.created).fetch()
```

which will order and fetch your (let's say) `Post` entities in the descending order of insertion dates.

Comment: this is exactly what i had in mind to do if there was no incremental key.

Comment: Consider to use timestamp with some random hash as a key for optimization purposes.

Comment: Can you explain this a little bit further?

Comment: @DmitrySadovnychyi, yes, please expound on that: seems interesting!

Comment: By default results are sorted by key, so, make your key to look like "TIMESPAMP.RANDOMHASH" for example: `"1431760275.asdh78g"` and `"1431760276.asdh78g"` -- you will get your results sorted by them.

Answer (score 0):

It's not expected that the order would be preserved unless you perform a query that would retrieve then in a particular order.

What makes you think they should be ordered?